# I can't understand how to prove the equation $(A\oplus B)\cup(A\cap B)=A\cup B$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that $(A\oplus B)\cup(A\cap B)=A\cup B$. Please check my work. I've tried to do it this way but can't prove it.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(A\oplus B)\cup(A\cap B)&=((A\cup B)\cap(A'\cup B'))\cup(A\cap B)\\
&=((A\cap B)\cup(A\cup B))\cap((A\cap B)\cup\overline{(A\cap B)})\\
&=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cup B)\\
&=\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: (Assuming all previous steps are correct) By the [absorption law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets), $((A\cap B)\cup A)\cup B = A\cup B$.

Comment: please define the circle-plus notation

Comment: I've transcribed the work in your image into LaTeX, added a more descriptive title, and fixed some minor grammar mistakes. The changes should show up in a bit once they've been approved. Once that happens, please check that I have not messed anything up. In the future you're going to want to typeset your work in LaTeX (with MathJax). [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from where you stopped:

$$(A \ \cap \ B) \ \cup \ (A \ \cup \ B) \\\\
=((A \ \cap \ B) \ \cup \ A) \ \cup \ B \\\\
=((A \ \cup \ B)\ \cap \  (A \ \cup \ A)) \ \cup \ B \\\\
=((A \ \cup \ B)\ \cap \  A) \ \cup \ B \\\\
=( A) \ \cup \ B \\\\
=A \ \cup \ B. \\\\
$$

Answer (score 1):

Going backwards from the first line of your proof to work out what $A\oplus B$ indicates, $((A\cup B)\cap(A'\cup B'))$ is the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$, and as far as I know it is usually written as $A\Delta B$ not $A\oplus B$. If $x\in ((A\cup B)\cap (A'\cup B'))$ then $x\in A\cup B$ but $x\not\in A\cap B$ since $A\cap B=(A'\cup B')'$. We can also write $A\Delta B=(A-B)\cup (B-A)$.

---

Assuming that's the case, let's show $(A\Delta B)\cup(A\cap B)=A\cup B$.

Suppose $x\in (A\Delta B)\cup (A\cap B)$ then either $x\in A\Delta B\subset A\cup B$ or $x\in A\cap B\subset A\cup B$, so $x \in A\cup B$.

Suppose $x\in A\cup B$ then either $x\in A-B$, or $x\in A\cap B$, or $x\in B-A$. Since $A\Delta B=(A-B)\cup (B-A)$, either $x\in A\Delta B$ or $x\in A\cap B$.

Answer (score 1):

Define these aliases: $${U:=A\cup B\\N:=A\cap B}$$

You can show that: $$A\oplus B=U\cap N^{\small\complement}$$

The rest is just showing that $$(U \cap N^{\small\complement} )\cup N = U$$ ... because $N\subseteq U$.